# Find the basis for $kerT_1 \cap kerT_2$ if $T_1,T_2:\mathbb R_4[x]\to \mathbb R$, $T_1(p(x))=p(1)$, $T_2(p(x))=p(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the basis for $kerT_1 \cap kerT_2$ if $T_1,T_2:\mathbb R_4[x]\to \mathbb R$, $T_1(p(x))=p(1)$, $T_2(p(x))=p(2)$.
>
> $\mathbb R_4[x]$ is all the polynomials of form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ over $\mathbb R$.

First $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\Rightarrow p(1)=a+b+c+d$.

$\text{ker}T_1=\{p(x)|a+b+c+d=0\}$ which means I need to find the general solution to $a+b+c+d=0\Rightarrow a=-b-c-d\Rightarrow$ the general solution is $(-b-c-d,b,c,d).\quad (\ast)$

In order to get the basis for $\text{ker}T_1$ I can then row reduce the corresponding matrix to $(\ast)$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&0&0\\
-1&0&1&0\\
-1&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be reduced to (the first column is row labels only):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1:&1&-1&0&0\\
a_2:&0&1&-1&0\\
a_3:&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Similarly $T(p(x))=p(2)=8a+4b+2c+d$ so the general solution is $(\frac{-4b-2c-d}{8},4b,2c,d)$ therefore the corresponding row reduced matrix is (the first row is row labels only):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1:&1&-8&0&0\\
b_2:&0&1&-1&0\\
b_3:&0&0&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In order to find vectors $v \in kerT_1 \cap kerT_2$ I need to find $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4, k_5,k_6$ such that: 
$$
v=k_1a_1+k_2a_2+k_3a_3=k_3b_1+k_4b_4+k_5b_5
$$

Which means solving yet another 4 by 6 matrix. I feel like I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: Instead of thinking of the elements of $\mathbb{R}_4[x]$ as $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, think of them as $a(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$, and recall that $p(1) = 0$ means that $1$ is a root of $p$.

Comment: What does ${\bf R}_4[x]$ mean? I've taught Linear Algebra since the dawn of time, and I've never seen that notation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the question in order to include the definition of $\mathbb R_4[x]$.

Comment: What you want to do is solve the system, $a+b+c+d=0,8a+4b+2c+d=0$.

Comment: But how could I find the basis of $kerT_1$ separetely?

Comment: @Yos $\ker T_1$ is all polynomials $p$ such that $p(1) = 0$. That means, by general properties of polynomials, that for any such $p$ we have $p(x) = (x-1)q(x)$ where $q$ is some polynomial. How you want to use this to expand to a basis is up to you, but you could take any three linearly independent $q$'s, stick them in the above, and you get three linearly independent polynomials that are contained in $\ker T_1$. Because we want to mix things up with $\ker T_2$, it could be a good idea to let as many as possible of the $q$'s come from there, which means $q(x) = (x-2)r(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Here's a method that doesn't use much linear algebra outright: Recall that a polynomial $p$ satisfies $p(c) = 0$ for a particular constant $c$ iff $(x - c) \mid p(x)$. As you've pointed out, satisfying $p \in \ker T_1 \cap \ker T_2$ is equivalent to $p(1) = p(2) = 0$, which from our fact (and by counting degrees) is equivalent to $p$ having the form
$$p(x) = (x - 1) (x - 2) (a x + b)$$
for some $a, b$.

Comment: Can you please explain what went wrong in my method?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your method exactly---one can continue along your line of reasoning to produce a solution. But it's not particularly efficient. Like Gerry Myerson pointed out in the comments, you want to solve a particular homogeneous $2 \times 4$ system, equivalently find the null space of a particular $2 \times 4$ matrix, which you can again do by row reduction.

Comment: Before I understand other approaches I want to understand what could be wrong with mine. If I were to continue I'd get the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\-1&-8&1&0\\0&0&-1&1\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which after row reduction results in 4 linearly independent vectors. But if row reduce the 2 by 4 matrix that Gerry suggested I get 2 linearly independent vectors in the general solution. So I must be doing something not correctly

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me where you got that matrix from. The matrices in your question are all $3 x 4$.

Comment: So I would get a 4 by 6 matrix by combining the $3x4$ ones. But that couldn't result in the same 2 vectors which I would get from Gerry's system as far as I understand because I'd have 6 columns

Comment: This is the 4 by 6 merged matrix I was referring to:$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0&0&0\\-1&8&1&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&1&1&-1\\0&0&0&0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ Or should I've organized the vectors into rows instead of columns?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's much meaning in that matrix. If you really want to use a variation of the method in the question and you don't want to use Gerry's method, you could always compute $T_2(v)$ for $v \in \ker T_1$---you already have an explicit representation for such $v$ in terms of three parameters, $b, c, d$. Then, $T_2(v) = 0$ is a nontrivial homogeneous linear equation in those parameters, so by rearranging $T_2(v) = 0$ you will be able to express one of the three parameters in terms of the other two and hence produce a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60901/discussion-between-yos-and-travis).

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem you have to solve the system

$$a+b+c+d= 0 $$
$$8a+4b+2c+d=0$$
This means that $d=-a-b-c=-8a-4b-2c$, so you have from the last equality that
$$c=-7a-3b$$
Now replacing $c$ there is
$$d=6a+2b$$
And it leads to the general solution
$$(a,b,-7a-3b,6a+2b)$$